# ios - Need navigation bar with alpha but NO translucent blur

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to set up the navigation bar to be black with 0.80f alpha, and without the translucent blur? And have views appear behind the bar?

So far, I have tried setting the background to an image with alpha. However, the background still looks sort of opaque, and I cannot see the views behind the bar...unless I set translucent to YES. But setting translucent to YES also adds in a blur, which I don't want.

This is what I'm doing:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithWhite:RGBValue(0.0f) alpha:0.80f].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and

```
 UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[MyViewController new]];
 [navController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

Comment: Setting the bar to not be translucent will make it ... uhm, not translucent, which is not what you want. Setting an image as the background should indeed remove the blur. Are you saying you seeing blur despite having a background image?

Comment: I want the navigation bar to be transparent to a certain alpha. Setting a background image with alpha does not seem to do the trick. And what I meant was that I want the bar to be transparent, and not translucent.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I think I solved it. I just had to set translucent to YES for it to work.

It *seems* that if the navigation bar has a background image set, then setting translucent to YES will allow the background image to show through without actually adding any blurring. This is exactly what I wanted.